# C#: Cannot instantiate Dictionary with generic collection as key

Tags: c#, dictionary, generics

I have the following code:

```
public class Graph<TNode> where TNode : IComparable<TNode>, IEquatable<TNode>
{
    private ISet<Node<TNode>> _nodes;
    private IDictionary<Node<TNode>, ISet<Tuple<Node<TNode>, long>>> _adjacencyList;

    public Graph()
    {
        _nodes = new HashSet<Node<TNode>>();
        _adjacencyList = new Dictionary<Node<TNode>, HashSet<Tuple<Node<TNode>, long>>>();
    }
}
```

The compiler complains at the part, where I try to instantiate the `_adjacencyList` Dictionary. It says that it cannot implicitly convert one type to the other. I was wondering, why is that? If I change the `ISet` in the Dictionary's key to a `HashSet`, everything works fine.

Comment: You can't. For the same reason that `IDictionary<object, object> dict = new Dictionary<string, string>()` would fail: neither `TKey` or `TValue` are covariants.

Comment: You have to instantiate your Dictionary with the same signature as you have declared (using ISet, not HashSet). You can then add to your dictionary using a HashSet (e.g. `_adjacencyList.Add(node, new HashSet<...> { // data here });

Comment: @StephenPorter Oh of course.. Thank you! :)

Comment: It would work if the type parameter of `IDictionary<T>` were [covariant](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd469487.aspx).  But it isn't, it is invariant.